# Atheros Wifi card detected only every second boot

Tags: boot, networking, dual-boot, wireless, atheros

I have a dual boot Win10 and Ubuntu 16.04, but use only Ubuntu. What happens is that every second boot (Shut Down – Press the  On button), my wifi card is not detected (no sign of it at all). It’s QualComm Atheros QCA9377, built in my lenovo laptop.

This is output of sudo lshw -C network when it is detected:

```
*-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: enp1s0
       version: 15
       serial: fc:45:96:52:d5:c8
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:124 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:a1204000-a1204fff memory:a1200000-a1203fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Qualcomm Atheros
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 30
       serial: 58:00:e3:d1:cc:51
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath10k_pci driverversion=4.8.0-36-generic firmware=WLAN.TF.1.0-00267-1 ip=192.168.2.109 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:127 memory:a1000000-a11fffff
```

And when it is not detected:

```
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: enp1s0
       version: 15
       serial: fc:45:96:52:d5:c8
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:124 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:a1004000-a1004fff memory:a1000000-a1003fff
```

I figured it has to be the fault of BIOS, so I played with its settings - the Wifi is enabled, I used Legacy Mode instead of UEFI, and disabled Fast Boot, all to no avail.
I also did the update & dist-upgrade, and installed linux-firmware.

What I also noticed is that if the card is not detected, I must shut the computer down completely, and then turn it on to make it work. Simply choosing “restart” doesn’t do the trick.

It is really strange, that it happens only every second boot.
Thanks for all the tips!

Comment: A friend of mine had this happen on his HP laptop, and we never did figure it out :\

Comment: I would advise you to, when in BIOS, to Load Defaults . Then check and disable Secure Boot. Then reboot and re-check your issue.

Comment: @WillemK I did as you suggested, but it didn't help :/

Comment: Bummer...  As you mention you must really shutdown the system opposed to a Restart, kinda makes me think the adapter fails to recognize or ignores the reset signal. As 'Android Dev' stated he never figured out the problem of his friends laptop. To save time you could consider opening your laptop and replace the widi adapter card or, even easier, buy the smallest USB wifi dongle you can find.

Comment: Please boot where it is NOT detected and check the log for any troubles on the PCI bus: `dmesg | grep 02:00`

Comment: Hi @chili555, I did as you instructed, but running this command doesn't return anything when the card is not detected (it does when it's detected).